# Showing 0 as index for output

Tags: c#

In following, it shows `0` as index for values.Format of output must be like:

```
2352:0.45678
9878:0.23423
..........
```

But after running, the result is like:

```
0:0.45678
0:0.23423
.........
```

After showing above result it runs again and shows

```
 0:0
 0:0
```

---

```
var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(useridseq, z));//for multiply two vectors
                    }
                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
                    {
                        int indexx = resultwithindex.Index;
                        for (int yyyy = 0; yyyy <itemori.Length; yyyy++)
                        {
                            lineitemori5 = fileitemori.ReadLine();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineitemori5))
                            {
                                string[] values5 = lineitemori5.Split('\t');
                                int itemidori5;
                                foreach (string valuewoow in values5)
                                {
                                    itemidori5 = Convert.ToInt32(values5[0]);
                                    if (indexx == itemidori5)
                                    {
                                        itemidseq5 = Convert.ToInt32(values5[1]);
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        sb1.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", itemidseq5, resultwithindex.result);
                        sb1.AppendLine();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
                }
```

PS: I have two data sets that I worked with one of them and calculate the result which each result has an index that is not real,for getting the real index, i must use another data set.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you get 'itemidseq5'?

Comment: If you mean where i define the "itemidseq5". it is a public varible which is clarify at the beginning of the script @OleksiiAza.

Comment: @user3403967 For the first `0` there might be several reasons `1` - `foreach (string valuewoow in values5)` - this is not executed even once (no items in the collection); `2` - if it's executed still `if (indexx == itemidori5)` may never be true, which is another reason to get zero, and `3` if despite all that you get into the `if` clause then for some reason `itemidseq5 = Convert.ToInt32(values5[1]);` is returning you zero. I can only guess where exactly the code breaks.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It shouldn't be hard to step through and find out exactly where the 0 comes from.

Comment: Thank you @Leron. May you specify your answer by comments on the code,please?

Comment: @user3403967 I'm not sure what exactly you mean with that. If it's not clear for which part of the code I'm talking about it's `foreach (string valuewoow in values5)
                                {
                                    itemidori5 = Convert.ToInt32(values5[0]);
                                    if (indexx == itemidori5)
                                    {
                                        itemidseq5 = Convert.ToInt32(values5[1]);
                                    }
                                }` that one :)

Comment: And btw, looking again at your code, there's a chance that you don't get even inside this if - `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineitemori5))`. You really need to put some breakpoints and see what exactly is going on.